# Recycler view notifyDataSetChange not working from custom adapter

Tags: xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I have a customer list. First time it renders with all customers, then I added a filter to list only new customers. Modified the source items with new customers. But it is not rendering in the view. Adapter constructor is called with new set of array. But it is not invoking the method public override int ItemCount. This page will get rendered on screen lock and unlock of device. Please help me here

```
public class RecyclerViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<RecyclerViewList, RecyclerView>
{ 
.........
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == RecyclerViewList.ItemsProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var items = (Element as RecyclerViewList).Items;
            if (items != null)
            {
                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items);
                adapter.ItemClickEvent += OnItemClick;
                adapter.PopUpClickEvent += OnPopUpClick;
                recyclerViewCustomers.SetAdapter(adapter);


                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
               // Task.Delay(500);


            }
        }
    }
......
}
```

Comment: Are you creating a new adapter with the filtered results ?

Comment: yes. New adapter created on applying filter.

Comment: Try using the same adapter and set the data. Using a new adapter on every search is not optimal. Although theoretically it should work. Can you put more of your code. Specially the adapter code ?